# 'NoMethodError in Posts#index' error in the index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timestamp

> This is my index.html.erb file

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="post_wrapper">
     <h2 class="title"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>
     <p class="date"><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want to change the line

```
<p class="date"><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %></p>
```

to `<p class="date">Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> Ago</p>` but it's throwing up errors. This line is working well in show page but got errors in the index page.

> below is my post_controller.rb file

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
before_action :correct_user,       only: [:destroy, :edit]


def search
      if params[:search].present?
          @posts = Post.search(params[:search])
      else
          @posts = Post.all
      end   
  end

  def index
      @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')        
  end

  def new   
      @post = Post.new  
  end

  def create
      @post = Post.new(post_params)

      if @post.save 
          redirect_to @post
      else
          render 'new'
      end
  end

  def show
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])        
  end

  def edit
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])        
  end

  def update
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])

      if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :date, :time, :location))
          redirect_to @post
      else
          render 'edit'
      end   
  end

  def destroy
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      @post.destroy

      redirect_to root_path     
  end

  def upvote
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end


  private
  def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :date, :time, :location)
  end

  def correct_user
      @post = current_user.posts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      if @post.nil?
        flash[:alert] = "Not your post!"
        redirect_to :back
      end
    end
end
```

> and here's my show.html.erb file,

```
<div id="post_content">
<h1 class="title">
    <%= @post.title %>
</h1>

<p class="date">
    Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> Ago
    <!-- To show edit & delete for sign_in user
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
    | <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %>
    | <%= link_to 'Delete', post_path(@post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    <% end %>
    -->
</p>

<p class="date">
    <%= @post.date %>
</p>

<p class="time">
    <%= @post.time %>
</p>

<p class="location">
    <%= @post.location %>
</p>

<div id="comments">

  <div class="btn-group pull-left">
    <%= link_to like_post_path(@post), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
      <%= @post.get_upvotes.size %>
    <% end %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </div> 

    <h2><%= @post.comments.count %> Comments</h2> 
    <%= render @post.comments %>

    <h3>Add a comment:</h3>
    <%= render "comments/form" %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
  <p class="date">Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> Ago</p>
```

to:

```
  <p class="date">Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> Ago</p>
```

In your index action (and the associated view), you don't have the `@post` variable (but you do in your show action). Instead, you have the `post` variable which comes from:

```
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
```